# how should I alter the launchsettings.json and frontend code to run this API that was originally running on localhost?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

Last year my team made an online boardgame for school. The frontend is html/css and JS. The backend is an ASP .net Core app. The frontend is already set up on my server using NGINX.
I wanted to host it on my portfolio site but the structure of the backend was provided to us by the teachers (i have gotten permission to host it) so it's not completely clear to me how exactly I should alter the code in order for the API to communicate properly with the frontend.The API was originally running on localhost.

What I do know is that I need an ARM Linux build to be able to run it on the server I have.
I am assuming that in the launchsettings.json I need to alter the applicationUrl from localhost:5000 and localhost:5001 to something else and then match the code in the frontend to that address but i'm unsure where it should point to.

Should it be the domain name that points to my server? Or am I missing something?

This is literally my first question here so sorry if it's not in the proper format or unclear.

[image: frontend request code and launchsettings.json screenshot]

The code for the launchSettings.json for the API

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53518",
      "sslPort": 44307
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Stratego.Api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

An example of a request in the frontend

```
get('https://localhost:5001/api/Game/' + localStorage.getItem("gameId") + '/board', headers)
        .then(response => {
            response.text().then(async function (message) {
                let parsed = JSON.parse(message);
                if (!containsBoard()) {
                    createBoard(parsed.squares, parsed.size);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! People will have a way easier time helping you if you provide the code as code directly in the question. Looking at an image is really uneasy.

Comment: To answer part of your question, since it's a bit too unclear for me: Your client code should contact your API using your domain name and maybe the port if it is not the standard HTTP(S) port.

Comment: @Salketer thank you for your response! I added the code fragments in question as asked. I had guessed that it would have to be as you described but wasn't sure as to how exactly to implement it. If you need to see other parts for clarification, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

This question is actually not difficult. There is a knowledge point about the `launchSettings.json` file that you may have misunderstood.

The launchSettings.json file is only for Visual Studio, generally for IIS, IIS Express and Project. After you deploy, this file will no longer take effect.

So all you have to do is deploy the program. Here I recommend a quick and quick way to test, I hope it will be useful to you.

**Steps**

1. create a base url in your angular project, then you can change the api url easily.

   Something like:

   ```
   var baseUrl="https://customdomain.com/"
   get( baseUrl +'api/Game/' + localStorage.getItem("gameId")
   ```
2. Enable Cors in your Api project.
3. Download `Ngrok` and run it
4. Run your api peoject, and we need to find the http port,like `http://localhost:7725`

   ```
   ngrok http 7725 -host-header="localhost:7725"
   ```
5. Then we can get a `https url` generated by ngrok. Use ngrok just test for deploy.
6. Copy and paste the url to base url. And you can test it.

*When you pass all the tests, you can choose your own cloud server or cloud service for deployment.*

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. My knowledge is limited and while it was not a solution, it did give me some further insight. I am unsure if that means I should accept it as an answer, according to SO guidelines. 
It seems this program was not really meant to be run outside of VS and localhost. It is not really an API project (in the sense of different VS project types) and because I have limited experience with Cors outside of that context, I feel like I'm better off focusing on other projects until I gain a better understanding of all the elements involved.